# How to make Function trigger only onCreate and onUpdate?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I want Cloud Function trigger only when document is create and update. I do not want Cloud Function trigger `onDelete`.

Is there any trigger for only `onCreate` and `onUpdate` without make 2 separate function?

I see Firebase have `onWrite`, but this trigger also `onDelete`:

> onCreate  Triggered when a document is written to for the first time.
>
> onUpdate  Triggered when a document already exists and has any value
>
> changed. onDelete Triggered when a document with data is deleted.
>
> onWrite   Triggered when onCreate, onUpdate or onDelete is triggered.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 10):

You can use onWrite listener with handler that does nothing in case of deletion.

```
exports.myFunction = functions.firestore
    .document('/abc/{docId}')
    .onWrite((change, context) => {

      // Exit when the data is deleted.
      if (!change.after.exists()) {
        return null;
      }

      //TODO: put code here you want to execute for create and update
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

There are no combination triggers, so you will need to declare two Cloud Functions for this.

But you can implement your actual logic in a single regular function, and then just call that from the two Cloud Functions.

Something like

```js
exports.createUser = functions.firestore
    .document('users/{userId}')
    .onCreate((snap, context) => {
      doTheThing(snap, context);
    });
  
exports.updateUser = functions.firestore
    .document('users/{userId}')
    .onUpdate((change, context) => {
      doTheThing(change.after, context);
    });

function doTheThing(snapshot, context) {
    ...
};
```

Comment: the above answer says to use onWrite, which do you recommend, onWrite or writing separate functions?

Comment: `onWrite` is probably a better solution for this specific case. My approach is more generic, and also applies in cases where there's no single trigger like `onWrite`.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Is it better to have `onWrite` and terminate immediately on delete or have 2 cloud functions, one for `onCreate` and another for `onUpdate` considering the number of cloud function instances being triggered?

Comment: Neither is pertinently better than the other. Having two triggers duplicates code, but reduces the number of invocations (and hence the cost). But you can see fro the number of upvotes, that most people seem to prefer ignoring the extraneous triggers inside the code - which is fine too.